# switching view black page

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to do a switch view. My first view is a storyboard and i want to switch for view2, i have no problem when click the botton in my first view everything is fine. The prolem is when i am trying to go back, the screen is going black and is not going back to the first view. Here the code that i'm using.

### ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)View2:(id)sender;
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)View2:(id)sender {
    View2 *second = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

And here the code that i am using to go back from the second view to the first.

### view2.h

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
```

### View2.m

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    ViewController *second = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Am I doing some kind of error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in View2.m

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

should do the trick

Apple has a [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) that I suggest skimming through

UPDATE
If you need to jump back more that one ViewController, you should use NSNotificationCenter or keep a reference to the viewController you need to jump back to.

In my experiences, the following line does 1 of 2 things (where self is a subclass of UIViewController)

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

1) If `self` has presented another view controller, the line above will dismiss all view controllers that have been presented on top of `self`

2) If `self` has not presented any other view controller, the line above will dismiss `self` back to the previous view controller

Comment: Thanks.. I was using this way before but when I add a third view from the second i was stuck in a loop.. not possible go back to the first anymore.. The was always jumping between the second and the third view.

Comment: @user1359374 I have updated my answer to address your comment